# ¿Como hacer dinámico la agregación de clases a los td de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo esta tabla, agrega la clase según el value, pero no me respeta el td, sino que del tr.
y como hacerlo dinámico si requiero n cantidad de registros?,mi código es este!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { validar(); });

  function validar(){
  var w =document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML;
  var s =document.getElementById("dos").innerHTML;
  if (s>5 && w>5){
   $('#dos').addClass('ale');
   $('#uno').addClass('ale');
  }else if(s>5 && w<=5){
   $('#dos').addClass('info');
   $('#uno').addClass('info');
  }else if(s<=5 && w>5 ){
   $('#dos').addClass('war');
   $('#uno').addClass('war');

  }else{
   $('#dos').addClass('sus');
   $('#uno').addClass('sus');
  }
  }
```

```css
.ale{
 background-color: red;

}
.sus{
 background-color: green;
 
}
.info{
 background-color: blue;
}
.war{
 background-color: yellow;
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"> 
<tr> 
 <td id='uno'>3</td>
 <td id='dos'>3</td>
    <td>texto sin color </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>3</td>
    <td>texto sin color </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>3</td>
<td>texto sin color </td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estas utilizando todo el potencial de jQuery.  Intenta no mezclar vanilla javascript con jQuery.  Seria algo asi:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { validar(); });

  function validar(){
                  var trs = $(".table").find('tr');
                  trs.each(function(i,tr){            
    var w =$(tr).find('td:first').text();
    var s =$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    if (s>5 && w>5){
   $(tr).find('.color').addClass('ale');   
    }else if(s>5 && w<=5){
   $(tr).find('.color').addClass('info');   
    }else if(s<=5 && w>5 ){
   $(tr).find('.color').addClass('war');  
    }else{
   $(tr).find('.color').addClass('sus');   
    }
                  });
  }
```

```css
.ale{
 background-color: red;

}
.sus{
 background-color: green;
 
}
.info{
 background-color: blue;
}
.war{
 background-color: yellow;
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"> 
<tr> 
 <td class="color">3</td>
 <td class="color">3</td>
    <td>texto sin color</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="color">6</td>
 <td class="color">6</td>
    <td>texto sin color</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="color">1</td>
 <td class="color">3</td>
    <td>texto sin color</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: no esta respetando celda, sino que agrega la clase a todo el tr, si le agrego una columna mas se nota!

Comment: En tu ejemplo tienes dos celdas y las condiciones tambien chequean las dos celdas.  Si se cumple la condcion, agregas la misma clase a las dos celdas.  Si deseas otra funcionalidad, deberias especificar bien que es lo que quieres.

Comment: Si quieres que agregue la clase solo a las primeras dos celdas, agrega una clase a esas dos celdas y cambia el selector.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta como te explique en el comentario anterior.

Comment: gracias alanfcn, perdón por no explícame bien, aun soy principiante!!